# How to use redux-saga with redux and react-redux

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-saga

I am trying to understand how redux-saga works, implementing a simple example (a button that when clicked fetch a user from an API and then the reducer adds this user to the store) with react, redux and react-redux.

Here is my saga (with console.logs for debugging):

```
import { take, call, put }  from 'redux-saga/effects';

import { GET_USER, setUser } from './actions/actionCreators';

export default function * watchFetchUser () {
  console.log('Inside saga');
  yield take(GET_USER);
  console.log('Received click');
  const URL = 'http://uinames.com/api/?ext';
  const user = yield call(fetch, URL);
  const userToJson = yield user.json();
  yield  put(setUser(userToJson))
}
```

Unfortunately when I click the "Get user" button nothing happens:

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';
import CSSModules from 'react-css-modules';

import styles from './Button.css';

const Button = ({ getUser }) => {
  function handleClick() {
    getUser
    console.log('Clicked');
  }

  return (
    <button
      type='text'
      styleName='button'
      onClick={handleClick}
    >Get User</button>
  )
}


Button.propTypes = {
  getUser: PropTypes.func
}

export default CSSModules(Button, styles, { allowMultiple: true });
```

Here the whole repo:
[link to repo on GitHub](https://github.com/SimoNonnis/react-redux-saga/tree/master/src)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem has nothing to do with sagas. Your code is missing "a glue" between redux and react in the form of `mapStateToProps` and `mapDispatchToProps`. Note that in `App.js` you are using `Button` component without props that is required for it to trigger a `GET_USER` action. Please take a look at this [redux documentation](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html) page.

Comment: That's true If I click on GET USER button I can console.log the click action but it seems like getUser actionCreator is not been dispatched and I don't understand what I am missing because before using redux-saga I was just using react, redux, react-redux and everything was fine

Comment: The repo you have provided indicates problems that have nothing to do with redux-saga. Your code is missing functions that I have indicated above.

Comment: I understand that is missing function, but I still don't get what is missing to trigger 'getUser'. Could you be more specific and try to explain?

Comment: it is explained in detail if you follow the link I've provided.